# Word containing "my", where the "y" is pronounced like the "y" in "yes"?

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation, orthography

Word containing "my", where the "y" is pronounced like the "y" in "yes"?

NOT a word where the "y" is pronounced like a different letter. They can either be in the same syllable or adjacent ones, as long as they're spelled "my".

I just need one example word, but I'm having a hard time finding even one...

Comment: Does *farmyard* work?

Comment: @PeterShor - Fiddlesticks.  That's what I get for taking too long.  8^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could only come up with one:

> ***[farmyard](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/farmyard)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. A yard surrounded by farm buildings.

Hope that works for you.